# Firefox 31.2esr: remove/hide menu bar items in source code

Tags: firefox, build, xul, menubar

I've created a local build of Firefox 31.2esr. Now I want to customize the Menu bar at the top:

[image]

I want to remove or hide some of the items completly (e.g. View, History...) or just remove/hide some of the options in an item (e.g. File --> Print). I've been able to remove some options from the "Help" menu item by removing them in the ../browser/base/content/baseMenuOverlay.xul file. 
In which files can I find the other menu bar items and options? I've been searching and trying for a while now, but I can't find them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `<menubar>` that is defined in `../browser/base/content/browser.xul` (the same directory as `baseMenuOverlay.xul`).  This can be accessed from within Firefox as `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`.  In the distribution, it is contained as `chrome/browser/content/browser/browser.xul` within the `browser/omni.ja` compressed archive.

It is also defined in the `chrome/webapprt/content/webapp.xul` file which is contained in the distribution within the `webapprt/omni.ja` compressed archive.

It is modified with the JavaScript in `chrome://browser/content/browser.js`.